# How to ensure that scheduled emails fail to send (SendGrid )?

Tags: email, sendmail, sendgrid

I scheduled some emails through SendGrid *without* using the "batch" functionality and I would like to cancel them. It doesn't seem like there is a cancel function through the api if not done using the batch functionality.

Is there a way to ensure that the emails fail to send at their scheduled time by doing some hackery, like: temporarily blocking/blacklisting email addresses, closing the account entirely, revoking keys, changing dns entries, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the scheduled emails by canceling the schedule. You can find more information [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/cancel_schedule_send.html). If the schedule has started and you want to stop the emails from being sent then you may need to clear the Sendgrid Queue. More information - [Link](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/stopping-an-in-progress-send/).

Comment: According to your second link (the first is only about batch) it seems the only way is to contact support - unfortunate.

Comment: To clear the queue you would need to contact support. I am afraid there is no other way. Sendgrid support is very responsive though. Shouldn't take you a lot of time.